# Is it possible to dynamically reconfigure a ConduitT step?

Tags: haskell, conduit, servant

I have a `servant` server implementing [a web socket ticketing system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security#authentication-authorization) for authorization. I'm using `servant-websockets` with [a Conduit endpoint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-websockets-2.0.0/docs/Servant-API-WebSocketConduit.html). I've defined an input message:

```hs
data WSInput
  = Auth {token :: String}
  | InMessage {inValue :: Value}
  deriving (Show, Generic)
```

and since the ticket will just last a couple of seconds, my conduit pipe will just check the Auth message for the first message in. The out message is like:

```hs
data WSOutput
  = PoisonPill
  | AuthOK
  | OutMessage {outValue :: Value}
  deriving (Show, Generic)
```

The pipe could be something like:

```hs
    wsConduit =
      mapMC checkTokenExists
        .| takeWhileC
          ( \case
              PoisonPill -> False
              otherwise -> True
          )
```

The pipe is just an echo after authentication. The `checkTokenExists` is just needed for the first message and in fact is blocking all `InMessage` so I cannot leave it there.

I could have some state in the `checkTokenExists` to let pass `InMessage`s after authorization but to me seems it feels like the best way would be to replace completely the `mapMC checkTokenExists` by a `filterC` just letting app messages in.

How could I dynamically change the shape of the conduit flow based on a single element of the inflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Change shape of program based on input" = `Monad`. And for this reason, `ConduitT` is a `Monad`, with operations `await` and `yield`. Just say what you mean:

```
checkTokenExists :: MonadIO m => WSInput -> m Bool

-- should be along the lines of
wsConduit = do
  auth <- checkTokenExists <$> await
  if auth then forever $ await >>= yield
          else yield PoisonPill
```

Comment: Thanks, one problem I have with haskell is restricting myself to the functions a given type provides but they are expanded to all typeclasses it instanciates. I need to get better at Applicative and Monad.
Just one question, isn't an impedance mismatch between the `await` and `yield` functions since the former is returning `Maybe WSInput` ?

Comment: Oh oops. Yes, the `forever $ await >>= yield` part should be something else to implement the echoing.